# View not found from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view

I return the View from my controller start_run1 to a view start_run1

```
public ActionResult start_run1(int? id) { ....
    return(View);
}
```

I get 404 page not found, even if I try using absolute paths etc etc.

if I add the code it finds the page but model data or ViewBag data doesn't get passed.

```
public IActionResult start_run1()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I have another similar controller function which works without doing this.

Any ideas, Ive tried everything.

Comment: Can you show the full first function? @Trevor

Comment: Incorrect - `return(View);` Correct - `return View();`